# Showing $E_1 \Delta N_1=E_2 \Delta N_2 \implies E_1 \Delta E_2=N_1 \Delta N_2$

Tags: measure-theory

Showing $E_1 \Delta N_1=E_2 \Delta N_2 \implies E_1 \Delta E_2=N_1 \Delta N_2$ in

[image: Halmos Measure Theory Page 55.]

Not able to show this even after expanding, can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in E_{1}$ and $x \notin E_{2}$.

If $x \notin N_{1}$ then $x \in E_{1} \Delta N_{1}$, so $x \in E_{2} \Delta N_{2}$ and $x \in N_{2}$. We have $x \in N_{1} \Delta N_{2}$ in this case

If $x \in  N_{1}$ then $x$ is not an element of $E_{1} \Delta N_{1}$ and neither is it of $E_{2} \Delta N_{2}$, so $x \notin N_{2}$. We also have $x \in N_{1} \Delta N_{2}$ in this case.

All other cases and contentions are entirely symmetric.